# Prove equivalence of a complex function

Tags: complex-numbers, equivalence-relations

How to prove that,

> $(z+1)^{100} = (z-1)^{100}$  is equivalent to $(z+1) = (z-1) e^\cfrac{2\times \pi \times k \times i}{100}$

Thank you.

**Edit:**

Okay sure, and I have attempted to do it.

First step is to take $(z+1)^{99}$ to the other side of the equation.

Then, $(z+1) = (z-1) \cfrac{(z-1)^{99}}{(z+1)^{99}}$

Then I believe the fraction should be equivalent to something??

Comment: Welome to MSE. This is not a homework website. You should at least show that what you have tried for solving this and why you cannot solve it so others will help you to get through it. :) Write down your own solution and show why you fail to solve.

Comment: $e^{2k\pi i} = 1$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^{100}=1
$$
and that $e^{2\pi ki}=1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $z\neq 1$, so
$$
\begin{align*}
  (z + 1)^{100} = (z - 1)^{100}
  &\iff Z^{100} = 1 \quad\text{where}\quad Z = (z + 1)/(z - 1) \\
  &\iff
  \begin{cases}
    \lvert Z^{100} \rvert = \lvert 1 \rvert \\
    \arg(Z^{100}) \equiv \arg(1) \pmod{2\mathrm{\pi}} \\
  \end{cases} \\
  &\iff
  \begin{cases}
    \lvert {Z} \rvert^{100} = 1 \\
    100 \arg Z \equiv 0 \pmod{2\mathrm{\pi}}
  \end{cases} \\
  &\iff
  \begin{cases}
    \lvert Z \rvert = 1 \\
     \arg Z \equiv 0 \pmod{2\mathrm{\pi}/100}
  \end{cases} \\
  &\iff
    Z = \mathrm{e}^{2\mathrm{i}k\mathrm{\pi}/100} \quad\text{where}\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}\\
  &\iff 
    z + 1 = (z - 1) \mathrm{e}^{2\mathrm{i}k\mathrm{\pi}/100} \quad\text{where}\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.
\end{align*}
$$